# Load More Cell UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to add Load More Cell to my tableview. Begin with 5 rows and when I click Load More Cell and add more 5 rows. All work fine without load more cell has image but I don't want it. I tried to fix it but it does not work.

Table begin 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld2ED.png

Table after click Load More Cell
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5xjE.png

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

#define IMAGE_VIEW_TAG 99
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        //create new cell
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        //add AsyncImageView to cell
        AsyncImageView *imageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f, 5.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f)];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        imageView.tag = IMAGE_VIEW_TAG;
        [cell addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];

        //common settings
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.indentationWidth = 44.0f;
        cell.indentationLevel = 1;
        //get image view
        AsyncImageView *imgView = (AsyncImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:IMAGE_VIEW_TAG];

        //cancel loading previous image for cell
        [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:imgView];

        //load the image

        imgView.imageURL = [imageURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //display image path
        cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];


    }


   else if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Load More...", @"The text to display to load more content"), kNumberOfItemsToAdd];
        cell.imageView.image = Nil;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.196f green:0.3098f blue:0.52f alpha:1.f];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.f];

    }
```

numberOfSection

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (numberOfItemsToDisplay == [tableData count]) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 2;
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//    return 5;
//    return tableData.count;
    if (section == 0) {
        return numberOfItemsToDisplay;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }


}
```

Comment: Find a way to detect the "Load more" table cell and then set the imageView to nil

Comment: i set cell.imageView.image = Nil;
but the Load More cell still has Image

Comment: can you update your code to reflect the changes you mentioned in your comment?

Comment: i set i set cell.imageView.image = Nil; in "else if (indexPath.section == 1)" because the loadmore cell in section 1

Comment: From your image, it does not look like the "Load more" cell is in its own section. It looks like it is the last row in section 0. Are you sure the "Load more" cell is in section 1?

Comment: Sorry im new in Xcode. I dont know, i think i call it in Section 1 with that? 
else if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Load More...", @"The text to display to load more content"), kNumberOfItemsToAdd];
        cell.imageView.image = Nil;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.196f green:0.3098f blue:0.52f alpha:1.f];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.f];

    }

Comment: Did i need edit something in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: post your UITableViewDataSource method: numberOfSectionsInTableView

Comment: i updated on bottom of my question

Comment: so I'm not sure what numberOfItemsToDisplay is and when that value changes. Instead of putting them in separate sections, why don't you just add one more row for the "Load More" cell in section 0?

Comment: numberOfItemsToDisplay is 5 cell from begining. I use PartialTable https://github.com/Abizern/PartialTable to add "Load More Cell" to my table. I tried another same as you said but table doesn't show "Load More Cell". I think "Scroll down to load more" is better but i didn't find any examle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this:

```
else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: absolute, sorry i just forgot it :D

Comment: moving forward, you might want to check if (cell == nil) before you allocate a new cell. Since dequeueReusableCell might return a usable cell...